# How to access System.Environment from C++ in a Windows Store App?

Tags: c++, windows-runtime, c++-cx

I am trying to debug a deadlock between several threads in a Windows (Metro) Store app written in C++, and it would be helpful to have each thread store it's ID at various points so I can figure out which thread each of the other block threads is waiting for.

The [.NET for Windows Store apps overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302) says to use [Environment::CurrentManagedThreadId](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.environment.currentmanagedthreadid) in the System namespace to access the thread.  I would have thought I could simply write:

```
int threadId = System::Environment::CurrentManagedThreadId;
```

but, Visual Studio 2012 complains that "'System': is not a class or namespace name", when I try to compile the cpp file.

Am I missing a header file that defines the System namespace?  I don't see any header files listed in the System.Environment or Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId web pages.

FWIW, the object browser within Visual Studio 2012 shows me the System.Environment object, and the object browser shows that it should have a CurrentManagedThreadId property.

Comment: C++/CX is not .NET, so a .NET overview isn't the resource you should be reading. ;-]

Comment: @JamesMcNellis can you point me to the documentation for how to call P/Invoke from C++/CX code?  I thought it was only for .Net.  I am having a terrible time figuring out which documentation applies to C++/CX vs. C++/CLI.

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and did not realize you were using C++ (apparently I was not paying attention...).  Anyway, no, you don't need to P/Invoke at all.  You can just call the function as you would any other function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++/CX does not target .NET.  You cannot use the .NET Framework directly from C++/CX code.

You can use the Windows API function [`GetCurrentThreadId`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683183.aspx) to get the current thread identifier.